# Redirect to /error instead of /oauth2/authorize with new spring-security-oauth2-autorization-server

Tags: spring-security

I am using react client and new spring-security-oauth2-autorization-server. And I've configured public-client as was suggested in this [video](https://tanzu.vmware.com/content/webinars/mar-10-getting-started-with-spring-authorization-server) .  At my local machine after entering login and password everything is ok auth server redirects me to `/oauth2/authorize` and then back to react app with code. But at testing environment (in my case it is Kubernetes with two containers) auth server redirects on `/error?client_id=public-client&redirect_uri=...`. I enabled TRACE all application but logs don't answer me where is the problem. Here is part of the log.

```
20220513 14:26:58 DEBUG o.s.s.a.d.DaoAuthenticationProvider:199 - Authenticated user
20220513 14:26:58 TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:264 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
20220513 14:26:58 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy:79 - Preparing session with ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy (1/2)
20220513 14:26:58 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.s.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy:99 - Changed session id from F2238B1D17F13C607CC13DD00AD262DF
20220513 14:26:58 TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:264 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
20220513 14:26:58 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy:79 - Preparing session with CsrfAuthenticationStrategy (2/2)
20220513 14:26:58 DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.CsrfAuthenticationStrategy:63 - Replaced CSRF Token
20220513 14:26:58 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:318 - Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=Surkov, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[message_v, user_c]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=192.168.11.254, SessionId=F2238B1D17F13C607CC13DD00AD262DF], Granted Authorities=[message_v, user_c]]
20220513 14:26:58 TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:264 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
20220513 14:26:58 DEBUG o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy:57 - Redirecting to https://192.168.25.55/auth/error?client_id=public-client&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F192.168.25.55&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=0df5af37f09c46a7ae2f7cedca3991b4&code_challenge=LDBXhJi-uyu8rWgbneAqN19RQf7f5LJSwgJU3SCnrqg&code_challenge_method=S256&response_mode=query
20220513 14:26:58 DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:361 - Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=Surkov, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[message_v, user_c]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=192.168.11.254, SessionId=F2238B1D17F13C607CC13DD00AD262DF], Granted Authorities=[message_v, user_c]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@27cd0b2e]
```

Here we can see that `Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` with `Authenticated=true` but than it redirects to `/error` without any additional information about error.

BTW i use `SameSate=None` cookie and https at testing env.

`JSESSIONID=4E559F0CCBE6258B590DD4809ECB3D3F; Path=/auth; HttpOnly; SameSite=None; Secure`

```
@Bean
public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {

        log.warn("clientRedirectUrl1 "+clientRedirectUrl1);
        log.warn("issuer "+issuer);

        HashSet<String> redirects = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(clientRedirectUrl1, clientRedirectUrl2, clientRedirectUrl3));

        
        RegisteredClient publicClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("public-client")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .redirectUri(clientRedirectUrl1)
                .redirectUri(clientRedirectUrl2)
                .redirectUri(clientRedirectUrl3)
                .postLogoutRedirectUri(clientRedirectUrl1)
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope("message.read")
                .scope("message.write")
                .tokenSettings(TokenSettings.builder().accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofHours(8)).build())
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(false).requireProofKey(true).build())
                .build();

        jdbcTemplate.update("delete from oauth2_authorization;");
        jdbcTemplate.update("delete from oauth2_authorization_consent;");
        jdbcTemplate.update("delete from oauth2_registered_client;");


        // Save registered client in db as if in-memory
        JdbcRegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository = new JdbcRegisteredClientRepository(jdbcTemplate);
        registeredClientRepository.save(confidentialClient);
        registeredClientRepository.save(publicClient);

        return registeredClientRepository;
    }
```

Comment: This can be caused by a few different things; commonly due to some disagreement between the client and authorization server configurations. Can you post your `RegisteredClientRepository` configuration as well?

Comment: Also, just to confirm, are you running your client on port 80? It's a little surprising to see no port number in the `redirect_uri`.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?.  I do have to ask, do you use PKSE challenges? I don't (and it doesn't work) but the video I watched does (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DaUGKnA7aro), and I'm wondering that is contributing to my problem

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working, that was k8s Ingress configuration problem. It redirects requests by context. And from outside world it seems like it is 80. BTW to get all this work on docker compose I had to run auth server on https. And to add trusted certificates to all resource servers. Anyway I post there my RegisteredClientRepository